# Contour plotting a function in matlab over n levels

Tags: matlab, plot

This script `f = @(x,y) (1-x)^2 + 100*(y-x^2)^2; fcontour(f,[-2,2]);`

draws the contours of the function, over the interval [-2,2]. Is it possible to display the contour lines over the levels 1,2,4,...2048, *i.e* over some v = 1:2:2048 ? The guide I found specifies how to do this for a matrix. Can I do this without replacing my function with some Z array ( The values of f on the interval )?

Comment: Yes, look at the [`'LevelList'`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fcontour.html#bu62qy6-1_sep_shared-LevelList) input argument in the docs: `fcontour(f,[-2,2], 'LevelList', 1:2:2048)`

Comment: Additionally, I feel like you want levels that are power of 2, however 1:2:2048 will give you all odd numbers between 1 and 2048. The array you're looking for is 2.^(1:20).

Comment: @hazeiio actually it's `2.^(0:11)`.